# Fresnel Glass on Spotlights / Headlights

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, displacement

Good day fellow Blenderers.

I have a task to model a rally style headlight, and some beacon lights too, all of which features a ridged textured glass / acrylic lens similar to the photograph below.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I was hoping to avoid geometry as there are some quite complex shapes involving logos to do.

[image]

Ideally I'd use a texture map of some kind, but I'm not sure how to go about it - as always, any help is very much appreciated.

Cheers!